# How to control renderAs PDF

Tags: visualforce, pdf, renderas

I have VF page which I need to renderAs="PDF". But before converting the page to Pdf we need to select the record. Can it be done in same page. Something like this - one load of the VF page display a output panel with record list and after the user have selected the record and click the generate pdf button by hiding the above list and convert the VF page to pdf by renderAs="PDF". Is this possible or we need to have 2 separate page. Please guide if possible how can I control the renderAs="PDF" what should be the value other than PDF in renderAs="".

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer. Please try to google first before asking question. Happy to help.
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2008/06/dynamically-cho.html

Comment: Just a link as an answer is not recommended. You should write descriptive answers and for additional information provide the link So that even if link goes done for some reason then also your answer helps some one.